# Make a jest test to fail on any error thrown?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, error-handling, jestjs

How can I make a jest test fail on any error thrown?

I have tried around a bit, but haven't nailed the syntax yet.

```
test('getArcId => Error', async () => {
    await expect(client.getArcId('skynet')).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

I get the error message

> getArcId › getArcId => Error
>
> expect(received).rejects.toThrow()
>
> Received function did not throw

However the following test passes, so the function I intend to test does throw (at least to the best of my understanding of what throw means):

```
test('getArcId => Error', async () => {
    await client.getArcId('skynet').catch(e => 
        expect(e.message).toBe('Command failure')
    );
});
```

Comment: In the title, it said "fail on any error thrown", while for the code it seems to fail when **NO** error is thrown.

Comment: I will look more at the docs later and see if I have misunderstood something. I want the test to succeed when the promise is rejected.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get `toThrow()` to work, but doing the tests like so did work;

```
it('throws on connection error', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    await expect(nc.exec({ logger: true }))
    .rejects.toEqual(Error('No command provided to proxy.'));
});
```

If I reject just a message;

```
.rejects.toEqual('some message');
```

Comment: Ughhh.. Took me forever to get this to work. Your answer fixed it quick.

Comment: this is very useful when you are testing a simple throw like: `if (!foo) throw 'foo is non-existent';`

Answer (score 7):

For Jest exception handling to work as expected, pass it an anonymous function like:

```
test('getArcId => Error', async () => {
    await expect(() => client.getArcId('skynet')).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

From the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror)

```
test('throws on octopus', () => {
  expect(() => {
    drinkFlavor('octopus');
  }).toThrow();
});
```

Please note the anonymous function. Yeah, that got me a few times :)

Comment: Using your suggestion I get: "Matcher error: received value must be a promise, Received has type:  function, Received has value: [Function anonymous]"

Comment: Making the anonymous function async didn't help.

Comment: return expect(....).rejects.toThrow();   works for me.
withouts the ".rejects"  doesnt.
inside the expect is a Promise beings rejected

Comment: Making the anonymous function async helped catch the rejected promise. Like this: ```test('throws on octopus', () => { expect(async () => { await drinkFlavor('octopus'); }).toThrow(); });```. Notice that the top level anonymous function is not async

Answer (score 5):

```
describe('getArcId()', () => {
  it('should throw an error', async () => {
    try {
      await client.getArcId('skynet');
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e).toStrictEqual(Error('No command provided to proxy.'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Short, code-only answers are often frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being flagged (again) as 'low quality', please add some explanatory text.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error thrown by a function

```
it('should return error message', () => {
    expect(() => fn().toThrowError(
        new Error('Error Message')
    );
});
```